# More interesting examples of spaces that are retractions?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I learned about retraction: A continuous map $r: X \to A$ where $A$ is a subspace of $X$ is called a retraction if $r|_A = id_A$. I made some examples. For example: If $D$ is the closed unit disk and $D' \subset D$ is the closed disk of radius $1/2$ then  $D'$ is a retract of $D$. The map is of course the map $x \mapsto a_0$ where $a_0 $ is such that $d(x,a_0)=  \inf_{a \in D'} d(x,a)$. Like this, other examples can be made where the $X$ is just a small "extension" of $A$. This is not very interesting. I would like to know what spaces that are retracts look like in general.

Please can you show me examples of space pairs $A \subset X$ with not so trivial retractions $r: X \to A$ like my own examples?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the *house with two rooms* of Hatcher (*Algebraic Topology, A. Hatcher*, p.4 : available [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html)).